# Does CountDownLatch work in Android Service?

Tags: java, android, multithreading

Sorry guys, there isn't much code to post.
I've the following program structure.

```
MyService{

initialize CountDownLatch to 2
call InterntService1 - in the end of IntentService1 decrement the latch's counter
call IntentService2 -in the end of IntentService2 decrement the latch's counter
latch.await()
}
```

The problem I am facing is : as soon as the thread service ( as part of the application's main thread) starts waiting, the Intent Services are not executed at all. It just waits there infinitely. Has anyone else faced the same issue. I know I could use handler / some other mechanism. But my question is, why is this happening?

Comment: Why can't you post more code?

Comment: don't use `await` on the main thread (as it is a blocking method). If you are using an intentservice, for example, it is perfectly fine to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From developer.android.com:

> **Caution**: A service runs in the main thread of its hosting process—the
>   service does not create its own thread and does not run in a separate
>   process (unless you specify otherwise). This means that, if your
>   service is going to do any CPU intensive work or blocking operations
>   (such as MP3 playback or networking), you should create a new thread
>   within the service to do that work. By using a separate thread, you
>   will reduce the risk of Application Not Responding (ANR) errors and
>   the application's main thread can remain dedicated to user interaction
>   with your activities.

I think you need to create and run a worker thread on your service code.
Take a look at **"Extending the Service class"** section in following url http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html